# Election winning Prediction of 5 Candidates using Linear Regression in python

Tags: python

I got one project in which I need to build a prediction model using linear regression in build. The case study is, need to predict winning of 5 candidates in an election. In this, I don't have any data and need to build data on my own but I am not able to visualize parameters. Can anybody help me in data building, it would be highly helpful.

Comment: What research have you already done? It is hard for us to provide a good answer without knowing what you have researched prior to asking this question. Also, a bit more detail on your project requirements might be helpful.

Comment: till now I have thing of below parameters, which are kind of performance matrix of any candidate.   Parameters are: Candidate Name, 
Lok Shabh Constituency,
Last Win,
Last Constituency,
Candidate Rank,
Party,
Party Popularity,
Leader,
Leader Rank,
Constituency Rank,
Number of Debates participated,
Number of Questions asked,
No of Private Member Bills introduced        .. But these are not enough to build regression model.

Answer (score 0):

you can start by get previous years election winner as your'e train data, if you don't have any train data , you have a problem in using linear regression (or supervised learning) after that if you want to use python try this step's :
[image]
use some code from this tutorial : https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/ or any other good beginner tutorial , you can join some comunity like https://www.kaggle.com/ and get some ideas from their kernel regarding to some processing of the data and tuning parameters

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this question, you need to create a model based on data you don't have yet. Presumably you will get the data later on, by which time the model should already be implemented. You can create a fake data set using the [numpy.random library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html). We's need more details on what exactly you're trying to do, though.